# How to throw error in BigQuery if zero records returned by subsequent statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to throw error or message from my bigquery script in case zero records are fetched by the query statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can run a statement to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.table AS ...
```

Then run a subsequent query to verify that the table is not empty:

```
SELECT
  IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset.table) > 0,
     'Okay',
     ERROR('No rows in the table'))
```